# Usage of semi colon for string matching in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, if-statement

I am trying to understand if we can use `;` inside string match ? Even though the below code doesn't seem to work ..but i am trying to understand what previous developer wanted to do.

```
if param.type == 'Team'
  search_url += '/type-Team'
elsif param.type == 'Agent;Team;Office'
  search_url += '/type-Agent;Team;Office'
end
```

Comment: That's a literal string comparison. What sort of values does `type` take?

Comment: `type` comes as string either `Team`, `Agent`, `Office` @tadman

Comment: Just a code smell I think, comparing strings like that is weird

Answer (score 1):

Usually untangling some code like this requires re-writing it in a simpler form:

```
case (param.type)
when 'Team'
  search.url += '/type-Team'
when 'Agent', 'Office'
  search.url += '/type-Agent;Team;Office'
end
```

If that `url` part is simpler and this is really just a white-list filter:

```
case (param.type)
when 'Team', 'Agent', 'Office'
  search.url += "/type-#{param.type}"
end
```

You'll have to investigate what sort of values you're receiving as `type` and what should actually be added to the `url` regardless of what's expressed there.

Comment: I am trying to understand ..how does `when 'Agent', 'Office'
  search.url += '/type-Agent;Team;Office'` work

Comment: That's just a standard [`case` statement](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression), part of the core Ruby syntax. If you're unfamiliar with it, have a look at the documentation there and other examples to understand it better. It's quite a versatile tool.

Comment: I am sorry if my question seems unclear ..but i am asking how does `'/type-Agent;Team;Office' ` work based on whether its `when 'Agent', 'Office'`

Comment: like how does it return `type-Agent` , `type-Office` based on when `when 'Agent'` or `when 'Office'`

Comment: The basic idea here is if `param.type` matches any of those items in the list then the code in that section will run. Only one of the matches will fire, and they work in priority, top-down. Experiment a little with it and you'll see.